# open several custom info windows at ionic cordova plugin google map

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova-plugins, ionic3

i am new at ionic framework. i am building an app, that working with cordova google map plugin.
 my problem is that: i want all custom info windows will be displayed after the map is loaded. i have tried many options, but still no luck.  Now it opens only one window per a click on a marker, and close it when i click on another marker. Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem?
thanks a lot!!

```
addMarkers(markers){
  for(let marker of markers){
    this.map.addCircle({
      center:{lat:marker.lat, lng:marker.lng},
      radius: 50,
      strokeColor: 'red',
      strokeWidth:1,
      fillColor:'red'
    });
    this.map.addMarker({

      icon: {
        'url': "./assets/marker.png",
        'size': {
          width: 27,
          height: 10
        },

      },
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
        lat: marker.lat,
        lng: marker.lng
      }

    }).then((marker)=>{
      marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
      .subscribe(() => {
      this.bindInfo(marker,  this.setDiv(div));

    })
    })

}

}
setDiv(div){

  let compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DivComponent);
  this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);
  if (this.compRef) this.compRef.instance.timeInSeconds = div.time;
  this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
  return div
  }
bindInfo(marker,  content){

    let info= new HtmlInfoWindow();
    info.setContent(content);
    info.open(marker)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't  have multiple info windows display simultaneous.

Source:
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/329